# On finite etale morphisms to affine non-singular curve

Tags: algebraic-geometry, curves

Let $f:X \to Y$ be a finite etale morphism over $\mathbb{C}$, where $Y$ is a non-singular affine curve. Suppose further that $X$ is connected. Is $f$ going to be an isomorphism?

Comment: The short answer is no. As an easy example, consider $X=Y=\mathbb{C}^*$ and $f(x)=x^2$.

Comment: Why did you think so ? "Etale is the algebraic analogue of the notion of a local isomorphism in the complex analytic topology"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a community wiki answer consisting of the answer from the comments in order to mark this question as answered.

> The short answer is no. As an easy example, consider $X=Y=\Bbb{C}^*$ and $f(x)=x^2$. - **Mohan**